# How to add custom text on Markdown' Parsedown PHP parser

Tags: php, parsing, markdown, parsedown

I have this Markdown text:

```
![alt](/md.png "title")
```

And after converting it to HTML with [Markdown' Parsedown PHP](http://parsedown.org/) parser (http://parsedown.org/) I get:

```
<p><img alt="alt" src="/md.png" title="title" /></p>
```

I need to add certain values before and after the conversion as well as inside the code such that the desired result would be like

```
<a href='#' class='some_class'>
  <p><img class='some_classy_image' alt="alt" src="/md.png" title="title" /></p>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this in a easy way? I'm open to an answer using Parsedown or another PHP parser out there that exposes this functions in a easier way.

Answer (score 4):

You need to write an extension that overrides the `inlineLink` method.

It should look something like:

```
protected function inlineLink($Excerpt)
{
    $Link = parent::inlineLink($Excerpt);

    # modify $Link to match your requirements

    return $Link;
}
```

See [the wiki](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/wiki/) for more info.